# URL manipulation in IFTTT

Tags: if-this-then-that, url, feeds

I have an IFTTT recipe that picks up `{{EntryUrl}}` from a trigger `Feed | New feed item`<sup>1</sup> and then prints it to PDF through the action `Dropbox | Add file from URL`:

`http://do.convertapi.com/Web2Pdf?Plugins=true&Timeout=60&ConversionDelay=5&CUrl={{EntryUrl}}`

However, I want it to print *another* URL's page, namely the URL resulting from the concatenation of `{{EntryUrl}}` and `print/`. (In the case at hand, these are pages quite different from the originals without `print/`.<sup>2</sup>)

The below doesn't seem to work:

`http://do.convertapi.com/Web2Pdf?Plugins=true&Timeout=60&ConversionDelay=5&CUrl={{EntryUrl}}print/`

Any suggestions on how to do this in IFTTT?

---

<sup>1</sup> Just in case it might help solving this, this is the `New feed item | Feed URL` used for the trigger:

`http://partnerapi.funda.nl/feeds/Aanbod.svc/rss/?type=koop&zo=%2fs-gravenhage%2f2514%2c2585%2c2513%2c2518%2f`

---

<sup>2</sup> Specific example (might not stay there forever):

`http://www.funda.nl/koop/s-gravenhage/appartement-48935441-prinsevinkenpark-19-bwnr-8/`

Note that adding `print/` to this URL not only changes the page, but *also* triggers a `File | Print...` pop-up. Could that be the culprit? I think not, because just running, **without IFTTT**,

`http://do.convertapi.com/Web2Pdf?Plugins=true&Timeout=60&ConversionDelay=5&CUrl=http://www.funda.nl/koop/s-gravenhage/appartement-48935441-prinsevinkenpark-19-bwnr-8/print/`

*does* work as advertised.

---

**Edit.** However, further tests reveal that even

`http://do.convertapi.com/Web2Pdf?Plugins=true&Timeout=60&ConversionDelay=5&CUrl=http://www.funda.nl/koop/s-gravenhage/appartement-48935441-prinsevinkenpark-19-bwnr-8/print/`

doesn't work from IFTTT (although it does work directly). It generates a picture saying "file not found". And the filename of that picture is `print.png`. Weird.

Comment: I just visited your last URL and got "bad request". I'm guessing the site sets some cookies or something, and you can't just jump to the print/ page directly.

Comment: @barrycarter I also get that. The question is a bit old, and refers to a site for houses for sale. I guess this specific one is off the market. (Or the site structure changed, or whatever...) Thanks for your interest though. Edit: actually the referred page (part of the url) is still there. Maybe convertapi is offline/broken?

Comment: Woops. I meant to say that the do.convertapi.com page sets cookies or something. In other words, you can't just jump directly to printing a page, you have to navigate their site (and thereby get the appropriate cookies) before printing. Some utility sites dislike it when people try to jump past their navigation.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using a different url to pdf service.
One that I just found that doesn't seem to require setting of cookies is [PDFmyURL](http://pdfmyurl.com).

`http://pdfmyurl.com/?url={{EntryUrl}}`

They also have other url [parameters](http://pdfmyurl.com/save-as-pdf) you can set.

---

Note: I'm not affiliated with PDFmyURL in anyway. They were the first service I found when Googling, that didn't seem to require going to another url first to generate the pdf.

**Update:** This service  unfortunately, doesn't appear to work with IFTTT, see comments.

Comment: I don't think you want the `print/` at the end. But otherwise I think it looks good. Good luck

Comment: Tested. A few new items arrived and they failed in an unexpected way. The PDFs read: "IFTTT - is no longer supported! We're sorry, you can't use IFTTT with our service anymore. Due to the abuse of many, the few have to unfortunately suffer." :(

Comment: How strange... and unfortunate.  Legal and moral questions aside, you could add a proxy layer in between. Your other option is trying to find another similar service.